# Wordpress HTTP API results in JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm Trying to correctly use `wp_remote_get` in my wordpress plugin which uses our API. The API checks the request body for `is_json`, which returns `4` - aka `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. Using cURL has the desired response. Here's my code:

```
$args = array(
    'body' => array('api_key' => 123),
    'timeout' => '5',
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'cookies' => array()
);

$result = wp_remote_request('https://myapi.endpoint/api/1.0/request', $args);
var_dump($result['body'])
```

var_dump: `string(13) ""api_key=123""`

whereas the var_dump of my cURL request is `string(15) "{"api_key=123"}"`

Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: WP has no idea that the API is expecting json. You're stuffing in an array, which WP is probably going to be sending over as GET query parameters, not json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc B stated, wp isn't sending json. You need to set the content type in the headers, and also send it as json:

```
$body = array('api_key' => 123);
$headers = array (
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Length' => strlen(json_encode($body)
);
$args = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => $headers,
    'body' => json_encode($body)
);
```